# Stacked objects still moving

Tags: unity-game-engine, physics

I made a really simple simulation where marbles fall down into bins. When they are all stacked they still keep moving (gravity pushing down / colliders pushing back)...

bad marbles

[image: 1]

I thought about checking the velocity and clamp it to zero if close to no movement... but then they would not be able bounce back (those already grounded can bounce up when others fall down on them).

What would be the best way to turn them into good marbles that stay still ? :-)  Any suggestions ?
Thank you.

Comment: For each marble on each frame you can compute [cumulative average](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average#Cumulative_average), see the formula in the end of the section . Basically you select `N` - the number of frames in the past for which you average. Initialize the average `avg` with the current speed. Then on each frame you add `avg += (currentSpeed - avg)/(N+1)`. The idea, is that the bigger your N is, the less your speed average is sensitive to rapid speed changes (such as when bouncing).

Comment: And when the speed average is near zero, you know almost surely that the marble has been almost stationary for `N` frames. So you can check if the speed average is near zero, and then freeze the physics / clamp the current velocity or whatever

Comment: @AlexeyLarionov Good idea ! I am going to give it try. Thank you sir.

Comment: @AlexeyLarionov Tried and... failed : avg increases fast when the marble is falling but once grounded the avg takes too much time to reach back to zero.

Comment: Reduce the `N`? There's also an [exponential cumulative average](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_smoothing#Basic_(simple)_exponential_smoothing), which decreases much faster. The formula would be `avg = a*currentSpeed + (1-a)*avg`. Here `a` is a constant between 0 and 1. You can play around with values of  `a`, and choose it so that you have more pleasant results

Comment: The closer `a` to 1, the faster the decrease (and it also mean almost no averaging)